# Tile Images for Zoom: How do I get to zoom level 10 without starting with an image that is 262,144?

Tags: image, leaflet, openlayers-3, tiles, zooming

I am trying to create a zoomable image for web display and have come across multiple sources to get this to work; leaflet, openlayers, etc. I have seen and followed some good tutorials. [Pedro's](http://build-failed.blogspot.pt/2012/11/zoomable-image-with-leaflet.html)

However I am at a loss for understanding the best practices for creating my images in the first place?  It seems that to achieve a zoom level of 10+ I need a really large image to begin with.  Trying to do this in Adobe Illustrator or Photoshop seems like a bad idea?  Illustrator only goes up to 16383 x 16833 and photoshop will go to 262,144 but is too much of a strain on my cpu.

As of right now I am using a tile slicing plug-in for photoshop and it is a slow process.

My questions are:  Is the best way to get higher zoom levels by starting with a huge image?  Or is there a way to slice an image, and then slice the slices of the image?

If I need to start with a humongous image is there a way to up-scale my image outside of a program like photoshop?

If I can slice slices what is the best method?

Thank you so much for your help and time, it is much appreciated!

-earl-

Comment: What zoom factor are you trying to achieve? A "zoom level" of 10 means a zoom factor of 2^10 = 1024x. Unless your images are in fact humongous, that kind of scales don't make much sense. Are your source images photographs, aerial imagery, or what?

Comment: Well my first image zoom level is 256x256 I believe that's how most tile systems work?   I could be wrong...  So my end result when zoomed in 8x is 65536.  Or 256 tiles @ 256x256.  So my original image to be sliced is 65536x65536.  The original size of the image gives me my highest zoom achievable.  1024x1024 image when split into 256x256 tiles only allows for like a level 4 zoom.

Comment: If you're using [gdal2tiles](http://www.gdal.org/gdal2tiles.html) (I'm assuming so, based on the tutorial you linked to), you can specify the start and end zoom level with the `-z` option, e.g. `-z 10-18`. Is this what you want?

Comment: specifying the zoom levels in the code makes sense to me.  My problem is generating the "levels" to begin with.  Im not sure how to generate up to level 18 without creating an image that is absolutely enormous.  This is what im trying to figure out.  Although I did go back and try to mess with the gdal python script instead of the photoshop plug-in i was using and I have no idea how to install the gdal-core and bindings?

Comment: Trying to figure this out now.  It looks like the python script has a way to size up the image before slicing it up.  Not sure how this works with resolution...  I guess this is where i am at right now?  Does that make sense?

Comment: The script is able to both downsample and oversample the original image. There is no need for a pixel-for-a-pixel correspondence between the original image and any level.

Comment: Yea, i havent been able to figure out how to actually run this script on a mac so im not sure exactly how it works.  i just assumed that it would do a very similar thing as the image slicer plug-in which does not allow me to choose the zoom level of the slices.  it automatically does it based on the size of the original image.  It looks like gdal does the same thing.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you need to start with a huge image. If your source is a vector drawing, you could save as something like PDF or SVG and do the high-resolution rendering in another program. See below for an example.

`gdal2tiles` is a nice thing and can do many projections, but it's slow for simple raster tile pyramids and needs a lot of memory. [`dzsave`](http://libvips.blogspot.co.uk/2013/03/making-deepzoom-zoomify-and-google-maps.html) is faster and more efficient with RAM. On this laptop with a 25k x 25k RGB JPG file I see:

```
$ time gdal2tiles.py -p raster ../wac_nearside.jpg x
Generating Base Tiles:
0...10...20...30...40...50...60...70...80...90...100 - done.
Generating Overview Tiles:
0...10...20...30...40...50...60...70...80...90...100 - done.
real    3m51.728s
user    3m48.548s
sys 0m2.992s
peak memory 400mb
```

But with `dzsave` I see:

```
$ time vips dzsave ../wac_nearside.jpg y --suffix .png
real    0m36.097s
user    1m39.900s
sys 0m6.960s
peak memory 100mb
```

It would be faster still, but almost all the time is being spent in PNG write. `dzsave` will also do the centring for you automatically, so there's no need for the extra `gdal_translate` step.

As well as JPG files, vips can load PDF and SVG with a scale factor. For example:

```
$ time vips dzsave ../ISO_12233-reschart.pdf[dpi=5000] y --suffix .png
real    3m11.029s
user    8m58.520s
sys 0m35.504s
peak memory 850MB
```

Will render the ISO calibration chart at 5,000 DPI, producing an image of 78740 x 47244 pixels. vips memory use scales with image width, so you'd need about 1.5gb of ram for a 10,000 DPI render.